# plot(x) doesn't return a plot or any output or any error after rutting x <- hclust(y, "ave")

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'm trying to follow the instructions given in [PDF](https://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/Tutorials/FemaleLiver-01-dataInput.pdf) to construct a co-expression network. One of the first steps is constructing a dendrogram. This is the code.

The link to [LiverFemale3600.csv](https://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/Tutorials/FemaleLiver-Data.zip) is here in a zipped file.

```
# Load the WGCNA package
library(WGCNA);

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

#Read in the female liver data set
femData = read.csv("LiverFemale3600.csv");

datExpr0 = as.data.frame(t(femData[, -c(1:8)]));
names(datExpr0) = femData$substanceBXH;
rownames(datExpr0) = names(femData)[-c(1:8)];


sampleTree = hclust(dist(datExpr0), method = "average");

par(cex = 0.6);
par(mar = c(0,4,2,0))
plot(sampleTree, main = "Sample clustering to detect outliers", sub="", xlab="", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, cex.main = 2)
```

Here the plot() doesn't return anything in RStudio. The plot window is blank, but it doesn't return any error either.

When show(sampleTree) is run I got the following.

```
> show(sampleTree)

Call:
hclust(d = dist(datExpr0), method = "average")

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 135
```

Comment: Your example cannot be replicated currently. [Check out the guidance for replicable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For example: what does `sampleTree` look like?

Comment: Do you have the data set?

Comment: I updated with a link to the dataset in zipped format, should I post in another format?

Comment: @Therkel I got the following for the show(sampleTree)                                
> show(sampleTree)

Call:
hclust(d = dist(datExpr0), method = "average")

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 135

Comment: I got everything to work in RStudio and in the regular R GUI. Have you tried running just the `plot` line? If you run the `par` lines you should be getting a separate plotting window. The graph will not appear in your normal plotting frame in RStudio.

Comment: for me it works. try to close graphical device first `dev.off()`, or all of devices from Rstudio `dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])`

Comment: @Jake it worked. It was the par lines. Thank you :)

Comment: Should I close this question? I can't accept comments as answers. @Jake do you want to put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run just the `plot` line if you want your plot to appear in RStudio's plotting frame. Otherwise running the `par` lines will open a separate plotting window, and the graph will not appear in your normal plotting frame in RStudio.

Comment: What version of RStudio and R are you using? I cannot replicate a problem running `par` before a `plot` call but I do remember some issues with the internal graphic device not working properly at one time with the (then) newest version of R (perhaps RStudio 0.97xxx and R 3.3.3?).

Comment: @Therkel I am using RStudio Version 0.99.451 (work computer, so I don't have privileges to update it on my own), and R 3.3.3. When I run `par` within RStudio it opens a plotting window just as R does, instead of creating the plot in the "plots" frame that exists within RStudio. Not sure if that's different with other versions of RStudio.